# Swift/Objective-c standard system text strings

Tags: objective-c, swift, localization

There are certain buttons in iOS that are automatically localized by the system. These can be found in controls like `UIBarButtonSystemItem`. Is there any way to access those system translations?

For example, i want to create a delete button in a view, with the "delete" text. I don't want to bother localising it using strings, i'd want to use the translations already available to the system. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: The referenced thread has a link to the Apple Developer Forum telling that this is not supported.

Comment: That's too bad. Thank you for your reply.